# How to deploy Windows Phone 8.1 app to Windows 10 Mobile device?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I am **unable to deploy my Windows Phone 8.1 app (XAML, appx) to Nokia Lumia 920 running Windows 10 Mobile v10512**. The deployment just fails with:

```
Error : DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
```

Deploying WP8.1 app to WP8.1 devices work. Deploying Windows 10 UWP apps on that Windows 10 Mobile device work as well. Even deploying that WP8.1 app on Windows 10 Mobile Emulator works.

I got machine running Windows 10 x64, Visual Studio 2015 with Windows 10 SDK v10240, all RTM.

Comment: Not sure that would be the problem, but is the phone set in developer mode? Settings > Update & Security > For developers > Developer mode

Comment: I think you cannot do that. You need to port/upgrade your WP8.1 app to UWP project.

Comment: [this answers saved me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38145886/3989143) to deploy wp 8.1 app to wp 10 device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to deploy my Windows Phone 8.1 app on Windows Phone 10 device, you check this similar question:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3b5a4a1-307a-418e-94d0-3d0c538eec21/how-to-deploy-windows-phone-81-store-app-to-windows-10-mobile-device?forum=wpdevelop

Before deploying you need to refer to this aricle(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Ff769508(v=VS.105).aspx) about how to register our phone device for development for Windows Phone.

Comment: In my case I had to hard-reset my Windows 10 Mobile device. After that everything just worked. Strange.