# Unexpected Error: -2147483638 while deploying windows8.1 application to me device

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-8.1-universal

I'm currently working on Windows8.1 Phone Application Development.
Application runs fine on the emulator but when i try to deploy it on my Lumia 535, It gives this strange error message (Snapshot).
**"Debug using ARM" is selected and my device is connected and unlocked.**
**HyperV is enabled too**
 thanks in advance :)

[image: snapshot of the error]

Comment: Could it be that you use an "long" value and try to input a too big value into it?   From −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 is a long.

Comment: Do you have any background task registered in your app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following.. Disconnect USB

1. press 'Window key' + R
2. type 'services.msc'
3. press 'ok'
4. In the list find service `Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc)`.
5. Right click on it
6. Select Restart

Connect USB and try again. (Hope your device is developer unlocked.)

Answer (score 0):

I´ve been through this hell for many hours. Tried everything. IpOverUsbSvc was up and running. 
The only solution in my case was "repair" option of the visual studio installer