# UWP Deployment Error :: DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2146958844

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I am facing "DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2146958844" error while deploying a game in WP.

Code does not contain anything. Its simple a Hello World program made in Unity & exported as "Windows Store" Project. Then I open that windows build in VS and deploy.

**Unity Version :** 5.3.5f1

**Visual Studio :** Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3

**Development PC OS :** Win 8.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988945906 while deploying Windows UWP app to phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384375/dep0001-unexpected-error-1988945906-while-deploying-windows-uwp-app-to-phone)

Comment: this is not a duplicate..

I am facing Unexpected Error: -2146958844 and on that question error code is 1988945906.. Moreover, I tried that solutions also however those doesn't solve my issue..

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the "UWP" in your thread title means you're developing a UWP app.

If what you want to develop is UWP app, please upgrade your PC OS to Windows 10 since Windows 8.1 actually doesn't support UWP development.

If what you develop is Windows 8.1 app, you could try to remove the folder of your game app both on PC and Windows phone, then rebuild a new one in Unity. Then re-deploy the .appx to your device connected through USB or available on the same subnet.

Before that, please remember to make sure your phone is in developer mode.
If you still cannot fix it, please try to repair your Visual Studio or restart your Windows Phone.

Hope this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143507/unexpected-error-2147483638-while-deploying-windows8-1-application-to-me-devic) can give you some hints.